# Testng - invalid version "6.3-201110161418": non-numeric "3-201110161418"

Tags: java, eclipse, testng, testng-eclipse

**Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.**

Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
Build id: 20160218-0600

**TestNG** 6.9.11.201604020423 org.testng.eclipse.feature.group    Cedric Beust

Testng is failing due to the below exception, have anybody came across this error before?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version "6.3-201110161418": non-numeric "3-201110161418"
    at org.osgi.framework.Version.parseInt(Version.java:170)
    at org.osgi.framework.Version.<init>(Version.java:130)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.getTestNGVersion(RemoteTestNG.java:87)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3-201110161418"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at org.osgi.framework.Version.parseInt(Version.java:168)
    ... 3 more
[ServiceLoaderHelper] More than one working implementation for 'null', we will use the first one
[TestNG] Running:
  /Users/../test.xml

===============================================
    wurfl
    Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.testng.ITestResult.getInstanceName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.TestResultMessage.<init>(TestResultMessage.java:133)
    at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.TestResultMessage.<init>(TestResultMessage.java:140)
    at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.RemoteTestListener.onTestFailure(RemoteTestListener.java:72)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1868)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1852)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1268)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:753)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:613)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1062)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:974)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:137)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:58)
```

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior changed few version ago and now the plugin is taking testng from the classpath first.

<s>The naming of the jar don't respect the expected format.</s>

But don't try to change it because your testng version is too old and the plugin won't support it.

Change the configuration of the plugin on the project and ask it to use the embedded version.

EDIT: It was the behavior before https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/224

Just upgrade your TestNG version because the version you use is too old and unsupported.

BTW, the plugin should provide a more understandable message and I created a new issue for that: https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/255

Comment: Thanks for the help!I do not have this option enabled "Use project TestNG jar" in my eclipse. How do I Change the configuration of the plugin on the project and ask it to use the embedded version?

Comment: Sorry, I was wring and I forgot that the feature was removed: https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/224 Just upgrade your testng version.